# MAUI Email.ComposeAsync function call throws FeatureNotSupportedException on Android

Tags: android, email, permissions, maui

I'm about to publish an application on Google Play, but my package was rejected because it uses this permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES" />
```

I included this permission in the AndroidManifest.xml because calling the Email.ComposeAsync function would result in a FeatureNotSupportedException without it.

```
        var message = new EmailMessage
        {
            Subject = $"Új funkció kérése / Hiba bejelentés ({AppInfo.AppName} {AppInfo.AppVersion})",
            Body = "Tisztelt Szoftverfejlesztő!\r\n\r\nKérés / hiba leírása...\r\n\r\nÜdvözlettel\r\n\r\n",
            To = [AppInfo.AppEmail],
            BodyFormat = EmailBodyFormat.PlainText
        };
        
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(AppInfo.DevEmail))
        {
            message.Bcc = [AppInfo.DevEmail];
        }

        //await Email.Default.ComposeAsync(message).ConfigureAwait(false);
        await Email.ComposeAsync(message).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

I checked the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.applicationmodel.communication.email.composeasync?view=net-maui-8.0#microsoft-maui-applicationmodel-communication-email-composeasync(microsoft-maui-applicationmodel-communication-emailmessage)) , and it doesn't specify which permission I should add for this function call to work or why it requires the QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES permission.

**These are the exception details:**

`Microsoft.Maui.ApplicationModel.FeatureNotSupportedException`

- **Message**: Specified method is not supported.

Call stack:

- `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF` in `Android.Runtime.RuntimeNativeMethods.monodroid_debugger_unhandled_exception` C#
- `0x1A` in `Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper._unhandled_exception` at `/Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/JNINativeWrapper.g.cs:13,5` C#
- `0x1D` in `Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper.Wrap_JniMarshal_PP_V` at `/Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/JNINativeWrapper.g.cs:27,26` C#
- `0x17` in `System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw` C#
- `0x6` in `System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__128_0` C#
- `0xC` in `Android.App.SyncContext.<Post>b__8_0` at `/Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.App/SyncContext.cs:36,19` C#
- `0xE` in `Java.Lang.Thread.RunnableImplementor.Run` at `/Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Java.Lang/Thread.cs:36,6` C#
- `0x8` in `Java.Lang.IRunnableInvoker.n_Run` at `/Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/obj/Release/net8.0/android-34/mcw/Java.Lang.IRunnable.cs:84,4` C#
- `0x8` in `Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper.Wrap_JniMarshal_PP_V` at `/Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/JNINativeWrapper.g.cs:26,5` C#

The best approach would be to avoid using the QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES permission. Is there a possibility to do this?

Comment: See the Android section of the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/communication/email?view=net-maui-8.0&tabs=android#get-started)

Comment: Nice one Jason! Thank you, How can I accept this as an answer?
I added this:
  <queries>
    <intent>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
      <data android:scheme="mailto" />
    </intent>
  </queries>

Instead of this:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/communication/email?view=net-maui-8.0&tabs=android#get-started), you need to add this to the Android manifest

```
<queries> 
  <intent> 
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" /> 
    <data android:scheme="mailto" /> 
  </intent> 
</queries>
```